# MVC3 Html Helper Method To Access Parent Container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How would I access a Parent Container to change its css in an Html Helper Method?

I know how to return Html but I don't know if its possible to access the Parent Container when Html Helpers are in fact supposed to render Html, not change existing markup.

If not how could I add HtmlStrings together like:

```
var htmlstring = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
return new HtmlString("<li>") + htmlstring + new HtmlString("</li>");
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What about using jquery to modify the DOM? What is the end result you are expecting?

Comment: @CDSmith I'm trying to 'highlight' the current tab, right now I have it changing just the link css but I need it to change the li css instead. I thought about using jQuery but I feel that's not the right solution.

Comment: Not sure why you would feel it isn't the right solution... modifying DOM elements is exactly what jquery is for.

Comment: @CDSmith I wouldn't be able to find the current page as easily; as with an Html Helper where I can just check against the route values.

Comment: HtmlHelper for parent element should take care of this. You cannot access parent html from inside you nested HtmlHelper call.

Comment: @seemenomore Do you know how to add (concat) the two htmlstrings together? I would just make the parent element but I'd like to include the ActionLink within it. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your guy's help. 

new HtmlString("<li>" + htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName) + "</li>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add Html Strings together or rather the ActionLink and text use this:

```
new HtmlString("<li>" + 
               htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName)
               + "</li>");
```